# Android: adb pull file on desktop

Tags: android, adb

Trying to copy file from device to desktop, here is a command:

```
adb pull sdcard/log.txt Users/admin/Desktop
```

But this command creates a folder Users/admin/Desktop inside platform-tools folder where adb is located. How to pull file to my desktop ?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use a fully-qualified path to the desktop (e.g., `/home/mmurphy/Desktop`).

Example: `adb pull sdcard/log.txt /home/mmurphy/Desktop`

Comment: looks like Users/admin/Desktop is full-qualified path.

Comment: @Jim: It does not have a leading `/`, and hence it is a relative path. A fully-qualified path on OS X or Linux starts with `/`; a fully-qualified path on Windows starts with a drive letter or share.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but my question is 'can we do the same thing programatically '

I have done somthing  like this

 ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("adb pull /storage/sdcard/s.txt C:/Users/401896/Desktop/adbPush.txt");
    Process p = proc.start();

And its gioving error to me

Comment: @SidharthDash: Your code might work on the desktop. If you are expecting that code to work on the device, you are sorely mistaken. If you are trying to write a desktop Java program that automates `adb` commands, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you show your code and your error.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am replying to this thread because i am not able to post new question :( . Talking about the issue i am running this java code in PC and want to copy a file from emulator to PC. I have google and according to best answers even in SO they have use the code as written by me. P.S. when i am using simple "ls" commmand its working fine. But while copying to PC its throwing error.

Comment: I needed to use `./storage/emulated/0/` for internal storage.

Answer (score 55):

Judging by the desktop folder location you are using Windows. The command in Windows would be:

```
adb pull /sdcard/log.txt %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
```

Comment: for windows systems this surely works. if we try adb pull /sdcard/*.txt %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ this could bring all the txt files present on the device.

Comment: i had to use `adb pull /sdcard/log.txt %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\log.txt` otherwise it said no such file or directory

Answer (score 9):

Be root, Define file on device and  define new filename.

```cs
adb root
adb pull /data/data/.../databases/launcher.db launcher.db
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, start up **Command Prompt** (cmd.exe) or **PowerShell** (powershell.exe).  To do this quickly, open a Run Command window by pressing **Windows Key + R**.  In the Run Command window, type "cmd.exe" to launch Command Prompt; However, to start PowerShell instead, then type "powershell".  If you are connecting your Android device to your computer using a USB cable, then you will need to check whether your device is communicating with `adb` by entering the command below:

```
# adb devices -l
```

Next, pull (copy) the file from your Android device over to Windows.  This can be accomplished by entering the following command:

```
# adb pull /sdcard/log.txt %HOME%\Desktop\log.txt
```

Optionally, you may enter this command instead:

```
# adb pull /sdcard/log.txt C:\Users\admin\Desktop\log.txt
```

Comment: Yepp! worked for me,  but it wont copy files to the actual desktop if there onedrive  got involved it creates another  Desktop  there. Not iconned. An od   demeanor

Answer (score 0):

List item

Use following command to pull data from ADB

**adb pull data/user/0/project package name/files/.local/share/dbname C:\Users\vijayalaxmi.k**

data/user/0/project package name/files/.local/share/dbname  this path you will get when you debug application. i.e database path

project package name example => com.example

instead of C:\Users\vijayalaxmi.k user your own path where you want to save your file. for example, c:\documents

Answer (score -2):

do adb pull \sdcard\log.txt C:Users\admin\Desktop

Comment: This is an old question that has already received answers and even has an accepted one - additionally, your path is wrong!

Comment: But welcome to stack overflow! Please poke around a bit and read some guidelines. Always happy to see new people join the community and contribute.