# How to edit and replace a default.realm file

Tags: android, database, realm

I am a senior Android developer but new to Realm.io

I have created models, wrote data on it + made queries without any problem.

Now what I would like is to edit the database using the Realm Browser so...

- how can I extract the default.realm file generated on my test app to edit it (I am using a Nexus 4 to make tests btw) ?
- is there a way to replace this default.realm with another one I have been given? We would like to work on the same dataset together with an iOS developer, that is actually why we chose to use the Realm solution, so we need to synchronize the default.realm files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tim from Realm here.

- As our [documentation](http://realm.io/docs/java/0.73.0/#the-default-realm) indicate, the file should be located at the root of the File folder for your app (`/data/data/<package_name>/files`). You should be able to pull the file from your device using ADB, per this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop).
- Yes! You can absolutely swap files in and out. Just replace the file on disk — as long as the schema inside the file matches your class definitions, then the data should load right away when you access the Realm.