# Extract Android Videos using ADB command

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am facing issuing in getting videos from android connected device using USB debugging.
what i am able to do is ADB is interacting with connected device and issuing command in that but.
I am unable to find a way how can i read/extract videos using ADB command.

```
$ adb devices
```

NOTE--**Not Able to get any any command**

Please let me know the way i can extract videos and save on my desktop.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: adb pull file on desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop)

Comment: Ref: `pull` : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: @SushiHangover i will try first hope it works or not but earlier i tried with some dfifferent syntax..thanks

Answer (score 0):

why you not try with manually android studio with USB debugging.Please follow below steps,

1. Please attach your phone to your system then open your app.
2. Checkout below screenshot and click to record video button.
3. After open your app in your phone and run it.
4. Stop it and save in specified location.

Thanks hope this will help you.[image]

Comment: thanks @saveen but i am trying my own without using any tool

Comment: hi can you try with this http://www.howtogeek.com/176956/how-to-record-your-android-devices-screen-with-android-4.4-kitkat/

Comment: its without any tool, you can record video with adb cmd

Comment: ok @Saveen but  my motive is to save video using adb not to record....thanks for the good description

Comment: @stylishcoder without record how you can save video ?

Comment: usin adb shell command may be i am not sure @saveen thats why i am here for more suggestions

Comment: Ok but i'm also not sure, is there any other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122250/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-saveen).