# Copying SQLite database in Xamarin Forms using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am actually working on a small app and I am emulating it on my Android device (Android 7.1 - clear flashed Android from LineageOS). My problem is that I need to take a look into my SQLite tables, but I can't find the file so I came up with an idea. If I can't look to it, because of Android, let's copy the file to computer.

But to be honest, I don't know how to do that. I found this, but my Xamarin telling me he don't understand that script.

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string sourceFile, string destFile)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection source = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}", sourceFile)))
    using (SQLiteConnection destination = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}", destFile)))
    {
        source.Open();
        destination.Open();
        source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, -1);
    }
}
```

He doesn't understands the `.Open();`....

> SQLiteConnection doesn't containts definitions for Open and there is no extending method Open..... (don't you missing some directives?)

Comment: use adb to view the files in your Android emulator image and copy them to your desktop

Comment: actually my PC is really bad for emulating, it takes really long and in most of times the adb stops responding, that's why i am emulating on real device

Comment: it works for devices too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on Mac/iPhoneSimulator

`var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
path = Path.Combine(path, "Database.db");
SQLiteConnection source = new SQLiteConnection(path);`

You can print out the path and open it in Mac

Answer (score 1):

While debugging xamarin forms android application run below commands in command prompt to explore the database content.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
TC25FM:/ $ run-as com.packagename
```

Below command copies the database content to phones sdcard

```
TC25FM:/data/data/com.packagename $ cp files/Storage.db /sdcard/data/
TC25FM:/data/data/com.packagename $ exit
TC25FM:/ $ exit
```

Below command pulls the file from sdcard to the dev machine

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb pull 
sdcard/data/Storage.db
```

Below command helps you explore the database using sql queries

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>sqlite3 Storage.db

sqlite> select * from tablename
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer