# How to view Database in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I just created Sqlite database in my Xamarin Forms project . I want to know how can I view my database to take a report of daily users or others records ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to access your db from within your app, or how to access your db remotely (ie, from your desktop)?

Comment: How to acces my db example from desktop to view all my user and other details that I created in Database ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org