# C#-Xamarin : create a .txt file on Device

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm a beginner in programming. 
I want to create a .txt file when I hit a button. How do I do that?
I've tried several codes... but my file doenst get created.

can't even see the foldern in emulator (Files)
it tells me my file is here:
***/data/user/0/com.companyname.projektnetapp/files/.config/myfile.txt***

this is what I'm trying. Am I wrong with this?

```
        var docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        var filename = Path.Combine(docs, "myfile.txt");

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sw.WriteLine("hi");
        sw.Close();

        DisplayAlert(null, filename.ToString(), "ok");
```

Comment: you need to use adb to access your device/emulator file system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop

Comment: still cant figure it out..
all i want is that a file gets created in the background , thats all

Comment: "can't figure it out" - what does that mean?  Your file is likely getting created, you just can't see it because you're using the wrong tools.  Use `File.Exists` in your code to verify the file is created.  If you still have problems you need to be more specific about what you've tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: @lockinson Hi , shared code is no problem , that just can not be seen in emulator . Because it's a hidden folder . I have updated an answer , you can have a look at it when you have time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From shared code ,  you have created and saved file successfully . That just can not be seen in emulator (Files) , you can use follow code to read file :

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

or `File.Exists(filename);` to check whether it exists .

> can't even see the foldern in emulator (Files) it tells me my file is here: /data/user/0/com.companyname.projektnetapp/files/.config/myfile.txt

This file can not be seen in emulator(Files) , because `/.config` is a hidden folder .

[image]

**However** , you can use `adb shell` command to see that , open **Terminal** in PC ：

```
adb root
adb shell
C:\Users\juniorj>adb shell
generic_x86:/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files # ls
generic_x86:/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files #
```

Now you will not see the hidden folder , you need to use `ls -a` to see the hidden folder :

```
generic_x86:/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files # ls -a
. .. .__override__ .config .local

generic_x86:/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files/.config # ls
myfile.txt
```

> The `System.IO` classes can be used to access the file system on each platform. The `File` class lets you create, delete, and read files, and the `Directory` class allows you to create, delete, or enumerate the contents of directories.

**In addition**, A text file also can be written using the `File.WriteAllText` method:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

Have a try with follow code :

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, "input content");
```

Here the `filename` is : `/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files/.local/share/temp.txt`

`/.local` is also a hidden folder , using `adb shell` to see the `.txt` file :

```
generic_x86:/data/user/0/WorkingWithFiles.Droid/files/.local/share # ls
temp.txt
```

The official document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#saving-and-loading-files

Comment: Thank you really much! Gonna try it out later! Of course I'll let you know how it went :)