# Can't see file created in the Xamarin.Android applicaiton

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, serilog, ef-core-2.2

I figure out that my application creates the file but I can't see it in the files folder (e.g. by using X-plore).

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var testFileFullPath = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(testFileFullPath, true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("Create test file");
}

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(testFileFullPath))
{
    var content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

What should I change to make file public and visible to browse?

**Update:**

Microsoft EF Core and Serilog SQLite sink can create databases that visible in the X-plore application (Android 10 emulator used). I also can specify any path I want (e.g. files directory). How did they implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From shared code , the `testFileFullPath` path is :

```
/data/user/0/application.package.name/files/test.txt
```

This file can be seen in emulator(Files) bellow ***Android 7.0 version*** .

[image]

Because from Android 7.0 , emulator can not access **adb root** permission . The solution that , you can create a emulator bellow 7.0 to test that .

About hidden folder , can refer to this discussion : [C#-Xamarin : create a .txt file on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762363/c-xamarin-create-a-txt-file-on-device/61765223#61765223)

Comment: I noticed that Entity Framework Core 2.0 can create a SQLite database (code first approach) that visible on the device and emulator. I want to understand how they achieved it.

Comment: @Pavel Okey, actually **SQLite** will create a `database` floder below  `/data/user/0/application.package.name/` the same as `files` folder . Then you can access the `.db` file from that .

Comment: @Pavel If answer be helpful , remember to mark that or vote up it . That will be helpful for other people to solve the same problem  :-)