# Accessing file explorer without having a android studio project

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a flutter project that i created and manage with vscode.

I now need to access some files on my android emulator.

Everything i read online references the File Explorer tool in android studios.

However, i am not using android studios and i dont have a android studio project.

The only way i see at the moment is to abandon using vscode and recreate my project using android studios then using the file explorer from there...

However, this seems silly and excessive... i am sure there is someway i can access the file on my emulator without having to trow vscode in the trash.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to open file explorer from flutter app ?? right

Comment: yes. this is what i want to do

Comment: `now need to access some files on my android emulator.` Use the file manager app on the emulator. Now a days its called Files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access emulator's file system from VS Code as of now. If you don't want to use Android Studio then an alternative way is to use `ADB Shell`.

Here are the commands that you can use to interact with the File System of your emulator.

- `adb pull` - To copy a file or directory and its sub-directories from the Android device
- `adb push` - copy local files/directories to Android device
- `adb shell ls`- List Files and Directories
- `adb shell cd` - change directory
- `adb shell rm` - rm is a command-line utility for removing files, directories and symbolic links
- `adb shell mkdir` - make directories
- `adb shell touch`- the touch command is a standard command used in UNIX/Linux operating system which is used to create, change and modify timestamps of a file
- `adb shell pwd` - printing the current working directory
- `adb shell cp` - copy files and directories
- `adb shell mv` - moves files or directories from one place to another

For a detailed example please visit [ADB Shell](https://adbshell.com).

Comment: thanks.... i think this is what i need to use, but agian this brings my back to my original question. where do i pull these files from? In the documentation for abd pull there is some sort of path to my emulator... I dont know what that is? i think there is something i am missing here?

Comment: @user254340 See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17629968/6915572